# Swift setting struct var based on another struct var (tried init)

Tags: swift, struct

**I've read a few similar posts about accessing struct members inside struct members and tried a few of their solutions. If you feel otherwise please comment before downvoting.**

I have an extension of *struct Grid* that needs to access a member of *struct Cell{ var state* in order to determine how many cells in the grid are alive. My attempts are commented out. Why can't I access `cell.state`

```
extension Grid {
    var numLiving: Int {
        return positions(rows: self.rows, cols: self.cols).reduce(0) { total, position in
            // let myState = Cell.state()
            // return myState.isAlive ? (total + 1) : (total)
            // error: instance member 'state' cannot be used on type 'Cell'
        }
    }
}
```

Cell definitely has a state member with an enum for state:

```
struct Cell {
    var position: (Int,Int)
    var state: CellState

    init(_ position: (Int,Int), _ state: CellState) {
        self.position = (0,0)
        self.state = .empty
    }
}

enum CellState {
    case alive
    case empty
    case born
    case died

    var isAlive: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .alive, .born: return true
        case .empty, .died: return false
        }
    }
}

struct Grid {  
    var rows: Int = 10
    var cols: Int = 10
    var cells: [[Cell]] = [[Cell]]()

    init(_ rows: Int,
         _ cols: Int,
         cellInitializer: (Int, Int) -> CellState = { _,_ in .empty } ) {
            self.rows
            self.cols
            self.cells = [[Cell]](repeatElement([Cell](repeatElement(Cell((0,0), .empty), count: cols)),count: rows))

        positions(rows: rows, cols: cols).forEach { row, col in
            cells[row][col].position = (row, col)
            cells[row][col].state = .empty
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `position` to access your specific `cell` from your `cells` property, and then call `isAlive` on that `cell`'s `state`:

```
var numLiving: Int {
    return positions(rows: self.rows, cols: self.cols).reduce(0) { total, position in
        if cells[position.0][position.1].state.isAlive {
            return total + 1
        } else {
            return total
        }
    }
}
```

Which could be written more compactly using the ternary operator as:

```
var numLiving: Int {
    return positions(rows: self.rows, cols: self.cols).reduce(0) { total, position in
        total + (cells[position.0][position.1].state.isAlive ? 1 : 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So that is essentially saying "give me the cell whatever the position may be and check the state" ?

Comment: The `positions` calls returns an array of position tuples.  Reduce loops through each of those positions keeping a running total.  `position` is a `(row, col)` tuple, so `position.0` is the row, and `position.1` is the col.  Using those, you can get the cell at that position from `cells` and then check it's state to decide if you need to add to the total.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how structs work. You are trying to access an instance variable of a struct that you have not created yet.

You'd have to do something like

```
var cell = Cell(...)
```

then call:

```
cell.state
```

In your grid extension you'd probably want to access all your cells that you have created for your game and then get the state from those.